# Найти самую длинную последовательность 0 в массиве

Tags: массивы, java

Дан массив. Найти самую длинную последовательность подряд идущих элементов массива =0, посчитать их количество, узнать индекс первого 0 в этой последовательности.

Напр.: 9 10 8 0 0 3 5 6 0 0 0 1 3 ответом будет 3 и 9 (элемент).

Что я делаю не так?

Считает только количество первой последовательности нулей. К тому же я решила сначала разобраться с нахождением верной последовательности, поэтому пока не считала индекс:

```
    public static void main(String[] args)          
    {   int s=0;//счетчик сколько нулей подряд
        int k=0;//количество нулей подряд
        int x[] = {2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 5, 1,  0, 0, 0, 0} ;
         k=s;
        {s=0;

            for( int i=0; i<x.length; i++)

               if(x[i]==0)
                s=s+1;
                else
                    if(s>k)
                        k=s;
        System.out.print(k);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Новичок, приложите больше *собственных* усилий к решению этой простой задачи

Comment: Нельзя быть таким жестоким)

Comment: Это жестокая реальность.

Comment: @a_gura  не подскжете ошибки если вы такой умный))

Comment: @liliya Вот если бы ты прислала фотографию, тогда возможно товарищи задроты были бы менее жестоки)

Comment: @liliya, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: @Vladimir Gordeev все сделала "сама")в помощи товарищей задротов, на данном этапе не нуждаюсь))

Comment: @liliya: Вот видите! Значит, мы всё правильно сделали.

Answer (score 2):

[[@liliya](/users/24332/liliya)](/users/24332/liliya), внутри `if (x[i] == 0) { ...` Вам нужен цикл, который считает идущие подряд нули (и одновременно меняет `i`), ну а потом анализ его параметров и запоминание максимума вместе с его начальным индексом.

Answer (score 1):

В цикле перебора массива, если встречаешь нуль, открываешь еще один цикл и считаешь, сколько раз подряд он встречается. Потом, когда следующее число не нуль, меняешь указатель внешнего цикла (чтобы не идти уже по пройденным нулям). При встрече следующего нуля повторяешь операцию с вложенным циклом подсчета нулей. Если нулей на данной итерации больше, чем на предыдущей - перезаписываешь их количество и указатель на начало последовательности, если меньше - идешь дальше.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int input[] = { 9, 10, 8, 0, 0, 3, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3 };

// StringBuilder понадобится для сбора из исходного массива
// элементов, чтобы затем превратить их в String        
    StringBuilder stringInput = new StringBuilder();

// а этот чтобы собрать наибольшую последовательность нолей 
    StringBuilder zeroes = new StringBuilder();

//сюда будем сохранять текущую длину последовательности нолей
    int length = 0;

//а сюда наибольшую длину
    int maxLength = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
//двигаемся по массиву, собиреам элементы в StringBuilder
        stringInput = stringInput.append(input[i]);

//когда встечаем 0, считаем последовательность нолей
        if (input[i] == 0) {
            length++;
        }

//когда встречаем не 0, сбрасываем значение счетчика нолей      
        if (input[i] != 0) {
            length = 0;
        }

//сравниваем и сохраняем наибольшеее из значений счетчика нолей
        maxLength = Math.max(maxLength, length);
    }

//собираем наибольшую последовательность нолей в StringBuilder
    for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {                       
        zeroes = zeroes.append("0");
    }

//превращаем StringBuilder'ы в String'и
    String numbers = stringInput.toString();
    String zeroComb = zeroes.toString();

//выводим рамер наибольшей последовательности, 
//используем метод indexOf, чтобы вывести индекс наибольшей
    System.out.println(maxLength + " " + numbers.indexOf(zeroComb));
```

}

Comment: Это, возможно, очень хороший код. Но плохой ответ. Объясните, пожалуйста, своими словами, что именно Вы написали и почему.

Comment: @SergeyNudnov это, возможно, очень хороший шаблонный комментарий (это не сарказм мне очень понравилось)